# switch between skin files depend on culture asp.net

Tags: asp.net, skin

I have different skin files for each culture in my asp.net program. I defined it to program in web.config. how can I switch between them ?

Comment: Try determining culture in Pre_Init method and apply valid skin

Comment: @malkam How can I apply it via code behind? I want to apply in in global.asax

Comment: Try in Global.asax.Application_BeginRequest method or custom httphandler

Comment: @malkam Thanks, Now how can I Change skin?